# Quando non ha senso fare l'analisi della concordanza dei tempi verbali tra reggente e subordinata?

Tags: verbs, grammar, tenses, moods

Una professoressa di italiano dell'università mi disse una volta che, per certi tipi di proposizioni subordinate, non ha senso fare l'analisi della correlazione dei tempi verbali tra reggente e subordinata. Mi fece qualche esempio che in quel momento mi convinse, ma adesso no riesco a riprodurre. Qualcuno di voi potrebbe fare un po' di luce sull'argomento?

Ho cercato sull'*Italiano* di Serianni. Nella sezione XIV.55 ho trovato:

> Il tempo verbale della reggente condiziona il tempo dell'oggettiva, sia pure senza la rigorosità della «consecutio temporum» latina.
> Se I'oggettiva è di modo indicativo si ha il quadro offerto dal seguente prospetto (il quale, oltre che per le oggettive di primo grado, vale, in generale, per tutte le subordinate che si costruiscono con l'indicativo tranne le ipotetiche, cfr. XIV.145 sgg.): [...]

di cui mi sembra capire che, quando la subordinata è all'indicativo, esiste sempre una correlazione tra i tempi verbali della reggente e della subordinata.

Più avanti, nella sezione XIV.57, si legge:

> Ed ecco il prospetto della concordanza dei tempi con un'oggettiva al congiuntivo (anche in questo caso applicabile alla maggior parte delle subordinate che richiedano lo stesso modo; per le condizionali cfr. XTV.145 sgg.): [...]

che non so bene come interpretare: cosa significa "applicabile alla maggior parte delle subordinate che richiedano lo stesso modo"? La concordanza dei tempi è diversa per certi tipi di subordinate oltre alle condizionali? Per alcune subordinate al congiuntivo non esiste nessuna correlazione tra i tempi verbali della reggente e della subordinata?

Su questo [sito di consulenza sulla lingua italiana dell'Università di Messina](https://dico.unime.it/ufaq/modi-e-tempi-verbali-tra-completive-e-relative/), individuato da @BakerStreet, si menziona che le "subordinate relative [...] non sono strettamente legate alla consecutio temporum". Nell'esempio

> Un bambino che leggesse per bene un'enciclopedia imparerebbe tutto ciò che una scuola può offrirgli

sebbene i tempi verbali siano il congiuntivo imperfetto per la relativa e il condizionale presente per la reggente, questo non significa che la relativa sia in rapporto di anteriorità rispetto alla proposizione principale. In questo esempio, la frase si può praticamente assimilare a un periodo ipotetico ("*se leggesse …imparerebbe*"). Invece, secondo questa stessa fonte, "un'interrogativa indiretta [...] è strettamente vincolata alla consecutio temporum". Quindi, se ho interpretato bene il contenuto di questa fonte, le relative sarebbero uno dei tipi di proposizioni subordinate per cui non ha senso fare l'analisi della concordanza dei tempi verbali tra reggente e subordinata (mi piacerebbe, però, avere una spiegazione più approfondita). Ce ne sono altri?

Comment: Non so a cosa si riferisse la tua professoressa, vedi se ti può interessare questo link, a un sito sull'italiano dell'università di Messina, dove parla appunto di subordinate che non sono necessariamente legate alla consecutio temporum, ma ad altri fattori, come il registro, e fa diversi esempi https://dico.unime.it/ufaq/modi-e-tempi-verbali-tra-completive-e-relative/. la mia impressione è che le frasi di Serianni si riferiscano al fatto che le regole non sono rigide, e molti casi restano fuori dagli schemi che ha presentato.

Comment: @BakerStreet: Era qualcosa del genere "con le subordinate relative non ha senso perché *bla bla bla*; per esempio, *bla bla bla*.

Comment: @BakerStreet: Suppongo che è quello che nella fonte che hai trovato viene espresso come "non strettamente legate alla consecutio temporum". Quindi, la mia domanda sarebbe: quali sono i tipi di proposizioni subordinate che non sono strettamente legate alla consecutio temporum? La tua fonte menziona le relative. Ce ne sono altre?

Comment: Io non è che abbia una competenza specifica, credo che ne sai di più tu, se mi venisse in mente qualcosa te lo dico! Non so se c'è una regola per dire che ci sono delle specifiche subordinate non legate alla consecutio. Lì ci sono esempi, ma non regole specifiche.